# Apache druid - Unable to run supervisors

Tags: druid

After downloading apache druid and zookeeper, I ran `./bin/start-micro-quickstart`

At http://localhost:8888/unified-console.html# under supervisor I am getting error -

> Request failed with status code 400.

java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

Apache druid - 0.15.1

Any idea what may be wrong?